# How can I get the Element if I am in the function of its EventListener

Tags: javascript, callback, addeventlistener

When my page changes, the eventlisteners of elements with a certain classname should be added. There may be multiple Elements with this classname. The elements also have an attribute called `taskNr`. When clicked, the eventlistener function should delete an element with the id "task" + taskNr of the Element, the eventlistener is attached to.

I have tried to give  the function a Parameter with the `taskNr`, but it changes to the `taskNr` of the last Element. That is why i now think about referring to `taskNr` from inside the function.

```
//fügt eventlistener für button removetask hinzu
function activateremovetasklistener(){
  var removeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-times-circle floatright fa-fw notfirst");
  for (i=0; i < removeBtns.length; i++) {
    var taskNr = removeBtns[i].getAttribute("taskNr");
    removeBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            removeTask(taskNr);
    })
  };    
}

//entfernt Task
function removeTask(tasknumber){
  var taskClass = document.getElementById("task" + tasknumber);
  taskClass.remove();
}
```

With this code it uses always the `taskNr` of the last element in `removeBtns`. It should use the one from `removeBtns[i]` (the element the eventlistener is attached to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object has details about [where it was fired](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget):

```
addEventListener("click", function(event){
    const element = event.currentTaget;
})
```

See also [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
 which covers why your approach didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can always access the relevant element inside the `click` callback `function` using:

```
event.target || event.srcElement
```

Your code should be:

```
removeBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
    removeTask(event.target || event.srcElement);
})

function removeTask(element){
  element.remove();
}
```

You can check [The **Event** interface MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) for further details:

> **`Event.srcElement`**
>
> A non-standard alias (from old versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer) for Event.target, which is starting to be supported in some other browsers for web compatibility purposes.
>
> **`Event.target`**
>
> A reference to the target to which the event was originally dispatched.

Comment: `target` could get a child element (e.g. if there was a span inside the button) and is best avoided.

Comment: @Quentin I just used `.target` and `.srcElement` for browser compatibility purpose only.